# Localhost on Windows 7

Tags: windows, http, localhost

I want to enable a localhost on Windows 7 to be able to build websites with Chrome without a distant server. I would like to not install anything, and be able to, for example, navigate to `http://localhost/something/somethingElse/index.html`.

Anyone knows how?

Comment: You don't need a localhost if it's pure HTML (Or even with Javascript), simply open that HTML file using your browser. PHP will require something installed though

Comment: Yes I know, it's just that Chrome doesn't "like" using file:///, javascript cannot set cookies, I can't import JSON files locally, and if I try to import them from a distant server it returns an error saying that a local script can't ask for a distant one.

Comment: Ok right, maybe could you give a try with Firefox : It allows some Javascript actions that Chrome blocks locally for security reasons

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In order to activate localhost server on Windows 7 navigate to:

```
-> Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off
```

Then search for Internet Information Services and check its checkbox.

Wait for Windows to make the changes, no need for immediate restart, the server will be enabled.

You can now navigate to

```
127.0.0.1
```

or

```
http://localhost
```

Comment: what kind of world do we live in where you have to 'turn on' localhost, sheesh

Comment: ^ A world where most people don't use localhost... :)

Worth noting: by default, Internet Information Services uses the contents of `C:/inetpub/wwwroot` for `http://localhost/`, so if you don't want to mess with settings, just throw stuff in that folder.

Comment: Excellent. One more question though: How do I make windows run a program/script instead of just returning an html doc?

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple chrome extension ["200 OK"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en). Which runs a web server on localhost.

- Custom port settings
- Choose your project folder and start the server

[image]

Comment: How can you add multiple web server locations?

Comment: @trobbins26 Then you have to go with node `http-server` you need to install windows version of  nodeJs and npm install `http-server`. After that you can turn any folder to webserver using `http-server -p 8080` and run multiple instance as well.