# Why GetUserMedia can't show video in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have my code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div >
   <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement" src=""></video>
  </div>

  <script>

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.msGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.oGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
            console.log("Browser supports getUserMedia");
            navigator.getUserMedia({ video: 'true' },
                      function(stream) {
                      console.log("on succes call back");
                      var video = document.getElementById("videoElement");
                      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                          video.play();
                      };
           },
           function(err) {
             console.log("The following error occured: " + err.name);
           }
     );
  } else {
      console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
  }

  </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

I've saved the above code into sample.html file. When I open the file in firefox I'm able to see the video from webcam.

Problem here is when I open the file with google chrome or opera (Crome & opera works similarly) browsers I'm unable to see the video.

My Browser's version

Chrome : Version 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit)

Console log from chrome is here:

> Browser supports getUserMedia
>
> Navigated to file:///home/xyz/sample.html

Can anyone explain what causes problem in chrome or opera?

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome does not allow `getUserMedia()` from a `file:///` url, while Firefox does.

To work around this, run a local web server and use `localhost/` instead, and put your file there. If you're on Linux or OSX, run something like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. For Windows [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340450/localhost-on-windows-7).

Or use Firefox. ;)

Comment: Thanks @jib it worked when I drive webpage from server.

Answer (score 0):

You need use command flag `--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing` or set it by open link `chrome://flags/#enable-usermedia-screen-capture` in browser.

**Upd:** I beg your pardon. Write wrong flag (thanks @jib) - you need use --allow-file-access-from-files.

Comment: Those flags are for screensharing only, and have not effect on regular camera/microphone access.

Comment: Sure! I made a mistake and written the wrong flag. We need to use --allow-file-access-from-files.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that one. Good to know.